# recursive view using lookup tables with ambiguous joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I don't even know how to title this question but I hope this makes sense.

I have three tables:

1. A table of users and their details
2. A table of groups and its details
3. A table of groups with the lookup ID of its members which are either from the users or groups table

The 3rd table has two columns:

1. A group ID which matches a row in the groups (2nd) table
2. A member ID which matches a row in **either** the users (1st) or groups (2nd) table

Notes:

- The IDs of users and groups table are unique against each other. For example, if a user has ID = 1 then no other user, nor any group, will have the same ID.
- A group can have either a user or another group as a member.

I need to dump a view of the 3rd table, fully expanding all members of each group, including the nested groups, dump the group path, and handle infinite loops. Hopefully this example makes it clear:

## 1. users

```
| ID | user_name |
|----|-----------|
|  1 | one       |
|  2 | two       |
|  3 | three     |
|  4 | four      |
|  5 | five      |
```

## 2. groups

```
| ID | group_name |
|----|------------|
|  6 | six        |
|  7 | seven      |
|  8 | eight      |
|  9 | nine       |
| 10 | ten        |
```

## 3. group members

```
| group_ID | member_ID |
|----------|-----------|
|        6 |         1 |
|        6 |         2 |
|        6 |         3 |
|        7 |         4 |
|        7 |         5 |
|        8 |         1 |
|        8 |         9 |
|        8 |        10 |
|        9 |         5 |
|       10 |         1 |
|       10 |         8 |
```

## 4. output/result

```
| group_ID | user_ID | user_name   | group_path
|----------|---------|-------------|------------
|        6 |       1 | one         | six
|        6 |       2 | two         | six
|        6 |       3 | three       | six
|        7 |       4 | four        | seven
|        7 |       5 | five        | seven
|        8 |       1 | one         | eight
|        8 |       5 | five        | eight > nine
|        8 |       1 | one         | eight > ten
|        8 |         | [recursive] | eight > ten > eight
|        9 |       5 | five        | nine
|       10 |       1 | one         | ten
|       10 |       1 | one         | ten > eight
|       10 |       5 | five        | ten > eight > nine
|       10 |         | [recursive] | ten > eight > ten
```

Comment: "Either" ugh....

Comment: What would really help is some consumable data in the form of create table and insert statements. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ I have no idea what the logic is here when you get "[recursive]". What does that mean? And how does the group_path value make sense there at all?

Comment: What part of this is the question?   Don't the existing posts about recursive queries contain the information you need?   I don't see any research effort here.   You should add a section that looks something like "I tried this, and I got this, but can't figure out how to do that".   IMO, "please write my query for me" questions are too broad.

Comment: @Sean: What do you mean by consumable data? Let me add some more detail about what you mentioned.

Comment: @Tab: My question is the "I need to dump a view of the 3rd table..." part. I've tried other questions but can't find anything similar to this. Maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing. I'll add some detail...

Comment: Did you miss the rest of that sentence, "in the form of create table and insert statements"? Or read the article I linked?

Comment: @Sean: You mean providing the CREATE and INSERT statements that someone else could copy/paste into their SQL server to create the tables? I've never seen anyone do that here before which is why I was confused. I'll add that. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an answer and a <kbd>**[live demo](http://rextester.com/RFIE70740)**</kbd>

```
;with cte as 
(
select id,name=user_name, type='U' from users
union
select  id, name=group_name, type='G' from groups
)
, cte2 as 
(
    select 
        user_id=c.id, 
        user_name=c.name,
        group_Id=g.group_ID,
        group_path= cast(c2.name as nvarchar(max))
    from cte c 
    left join [group members] g 
        on g.member_id=c.id and type='U'
    left join cte c2  
        on c2.type='G' and c2.id=g.group_ID
    union all
    select 
        user_id=user_id, 
        user_name=user_name,
        group_Id=g.group_ID,
        group_path= concat(c2.name,'>',c.group_path)
    from cte2 c
        join [group members] g 
        on g.member_id=c.group_Id
       join cte c2
       on g.group_ID=c2.id and c2.type='G'
        where c.group_path not like '%'+c2.name+'%'  
 )
 select 
     group_id,
     user_id,
     user_name, 
     group_path 
 from cte2
 where group_id is not null
 union all
 select 
     group_id=g.group_ID,
     user_id= NULL,
     user_name='[recursive]',
     group_path=concat(c2.name,'>',c.group_path)
 from cte2 c 
 join [group members] g
     on g.member_id=c.group_Id
     join cte c2
       on g.group_ID=c2.id and c2.type='G'
        where c.group_path like '%'+c2.name+'%'
  order by group_id,user_id
```